# Insert from one table with dupilcate data to new normalised tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, normalization

I have an old table with the following setup

**Emails**
[IdEmail]
[EmailAddress]
[City]

There are up to 5 different `City's` and there is some duplication of data with the `EmailAddress`.

My new setup has these two tables (which I've simplified for example purposes).

**EmailAddressListTable**
[IdEmailAddress]
[EmailAddress]

**EmailSubscriptions**
[IdEmailSubscriptions]
[EmailAddressID] (FK)
[MailingListID] *(City)*

How would I go about inserting the new data without copying the duplicate email address? Or is it easier to insert all the records with a simple insert and then remove the duplicates and change the corresponding ID in the link table? I'm a bit stuck as to how I would do this though.

**Update**

Just for clarification for example say the old table has the records:

```
ID  Email                   City
1   email@domain.com        1
2   email@domain.com        4
3   email@domain.com        5
4   NEWemail@Newdomain.com  1
```

I'd like to transfer this into the new tables like so

**EmailAddressListTable**

```
Id  Email
1   email@domain.com
2   NEWemail@NEWdomain.com
```

**EmailSubscriptions**

```
ID  EmailID  MailingListID
1   1        1
2   1        4
3   1        5
4   2        1
```

Comment: What do you mean by duplicate mail, only the mailaddress column is duplicate? or the entire column

Comment: The column `EmailAddress` in he old table has duplicate addresses to cover various cities, I want to normalise this in the new table with only one email address entry and multiple EmailSubscription entries linking the IDs

Comment: 1) Create new table 2) insert data to it 3) Modify EmailSubscriptions (add new column) 4) insert data into new column 5) delete column EmailSubscriptions with string address 6) remove duplicates

Comment: @progpow thanks for the reply but I'm not sure that approach would work - the ID's of the email need to match, simply removing the duplicates won't update the subscription link records with the correct email ID (and would most likely lead to foreign key restraint exceptions). `EmailAddressListTable` has a one-to-many relationship with `EmailSubscritions`.

Comment: @GJKH If on stage two you have table without douplicates do it solve task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the email address is the unique identifier for the matches and that the IdEmail column can be ignored in the "Emails" table.

You could do this:

```
DECLARE @EmailAddressListTable TABLE 
(
    IdEmailAddress int identity(1,1) not null,
    EmailAddress nvarchar(50) not null
)

INSERT INTO @EmailAddressListTable
SELECT DISTINCT 
    EmailAddress
FROM Emails

SELECT * FROM @EmailAddressListTable -- show emails in new table

DECLARE @EmailSubscriptions TABLE
(
    IdEmailSubscriptions int identity(1,1) not null,
    EmailAddressID int not null,
    MailingListID int not null
)

INSERT INTO @EmailSubscriptions
SELECT 
    newEmails.IdEmailAddress, oldEmails.City 
FROM 
    @EmailAddressListTable newEmails
INNER JOIN
    Emails oldEmails on newEmails.EmailAddress = oldEmails.EmailAddress

SELECT * FROM @EmailSubscriptions -- show matches to email in subscriptions
```

Comment: Thanks, works a charm and is actually pretty simple now that I've seen it broken down.